# Magento 2 checkout_cart_product_add_after not working

Tags: magento2, event-observer, addtocart

here am trying to add custom price during adding product to cart but checkout_cart_product_add_after event is not getting fired. 
my API to add to cart is

```
http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/carts/636/items/ [POST]
```

this is my events.xml

```
vendor/Cart/etc/events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Vendor\Cart\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

this is My Observer

```
Vendor\Cart\Observer

<?php

    namespace Vendor\Cart\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

    class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $_request;
        protected $_helper;
        protected $cart;
        public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,\TW\Product\Helper\Data $helper,\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
        {
            $this->_request = $request;
            $this->_helper = $helper;
            $this->cart=  $cart;
        }

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_quote_add_item', ['quote_item' => $item]);
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/test.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info("success !!!!");

        }

    }
```

Am not understanding where am wrong, can i get help? , Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it triggering while add to cart manually in the website?

Comment: its website is not in use. so I working through API calls, its not triggering

Answer (score 0):

`checkout_cart_product_add_after` is a frontent  event.It is not work with  Rest.

You can try with below event which can fire for all **area frontend, backend, Rest API, rest soap**.

> ```
> $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_quote_add_item', ['quote_item' => $item]);
> ```

Comment: Thank you for reply ill add and test it

Comment: I updated the code please check, its not working

Comment: what change you have done?

Comment: added dispatch event in observer